# How to obtain a provider and signer for sepolia test network on Metamask using ethers 6.6.0?

Tags: javascript, web3js, metamask, ethers.js

I can't quite figure out the problem when obtaining a provider and signer for Metamask!

```
let API_KEY = "....";
const getEthereumContract = async () => {
    // const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/{API_KEY}");
    const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/{API_KEY}");
    // const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
    // const provider = new ethers.getDefaultProvider("sepolia");

    await window.ethereum.enable();
    // const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" });
    const balance = await provider.getBalance("ethers.eth");
    console.log({balance});
    const signer = await provider.getSigner();
    const transactionContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractAbi, signer);

    console.log({provider, signer, transactionContract});
    // return transactionContract;
}
```

Error shown on console:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: network does not support ENS (operation="getEnsAddress", info={ "network": { "chainId": "11155111", "name": "sepolia" } }, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.6.0)

can someone help me with this issue?

Read through their docs and tried some solutions.
"window.ethereum" object works but I can't still get a good response?

Answer (score 0):

After careful troubleshooting, I realized that I can't call getBalance() passing "ethers.eth" as argument also JsonRpcProvider didn't workout for me.

So, I used BrowserProvider.

Here is the current code:

```
const getEthereumContract = async () => {
    const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(ethereum);

    const accounts = await provider.send('eth_requestAccounts', []);
    const balance = await provider.getBalance(accounts[0]);
    console.log({accounts, balance});
    const signer = await provider.getSigner();
    const transactionContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractAbi, signer);

    console.log({provider, signer, transactionContract});
    // return transactionContract;
}
```